# Error building Fuerte on OSX

Tags: macos, boost, ros-fuerte, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried building Fuerte on OSX Lion but got the following boost error:

```
[ 16%] Generating Lisp code from actionlib_msgs/GoalID.msg
[ 16%] Generating Python from MSG geometry_msgs/QuaternionStamped
[ 16%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/String.msg
[ 17%] Generating Lisp code from geometry_msgs/PointStamped.msg
[ 17%] Generating Lisp code from actionlib_msgs/GoalStatusArray.msg
[ 18%] Generating Python from MSG geometry_msgs/Point
[ 18%] Generating Lisp code from geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.msg
[ 18%] Generating Lisp code from actionlib_msgs/GoalStatus.msg
[ 18%] Generating Python from MSG geometry_msgs/Transform
[ 18%] Generating C++ code from std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray.msg
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/librostime.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in time.cpp.o
      boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int, char const*)in time.cpp.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in time.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/librostime.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [roscpp_core/rostime/CMakeFiles/rostime.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I was using boost 1.50.0 via homebrew.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42167/error-building-fuerte-on-osx/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-08-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-08-23**:
ok, for some stupid reason I cannot answer my own question!!!  The solution is to use boost 1.49.0, for some reason (I don't understand the error message) 1.50.0 doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reposting the answer for Kevin:

> ok, for some stupid reason I cannot answer my own question!!! The solution is to use boost 1.49.0, for some reason (I don't understand the error message) 1.50.0 doesn't work.

Should probably ticket this anyways so the problem can be fixed.

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2012-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-08-31**:
A [ticket](http://answers.ros.org/question/41889/cant-answer-own-question/) is already filed for this error ... let's see how long it takes to get fixed because it was filed 9 days ago and there still is an issue.